# What does the word もえる mean in the following sentence and what is the kanji for it?

Tags: meaning, verbs

Here's the sentence:

> もえるごみと一緒に毎週土曜日に集めます。

That sentence has been taken from the text explaining different ways of garbage disposal.

What does the word もえる mean here and is there a kanji for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[燃える{もえる}](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%87%83%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B) means to burn.

[燃えるゴミ](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%87%83%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E3%82%B4%E3%83%9F) means waste that can be treated and disposed of in incineration.